Upload tag video vimeo API
I can't upload tags of video to vimeo
Can anyone help me, I have a problem uploading tags for videos, my syntax is below
const uploadTagsService = async (videoUri, tags) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.request({
      method: 'PUT',
      path: `${videoUri}/tags`,
      query: {
        tags: tags
      }
    }, (error, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject({ status: 500, message: error.message });
      } else {
        resolve({ status: 200, message: 'Video tags updated successfully', data: body });
      }
    });
  });
};

My tags be like:
tags = [
    { "name" : "tui1" },
    { "name": "tui2" }
]

Result is:

{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "total": 0,
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 25,
        "paging": {
            "next": null,
            "previous": null,
            "first": "/videos/xxx/tags?page=1",
            "last": "/videos/xxx/tags?page=1"
        },
        "data": []
    },
    "message": "Video tags updated successfully"
}

Data will be null, I try to change
query: {
tags: tags
} 

by body, or data, it still not working
